# Embarrassingly simple bash scripting help

Tags: bash, unix, nohup, bin

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {0..999}
do
    if [$i lt  10]
    then
            nohup java BeginIndex ~actors/00{$i} ~/index_new/ > ~/results/actors_results/00{$i}.txt
            echo "INDEXING ($i)th directory completed "
    elif [$i lt 100]; then
            nohup java BeginIndex ~/actors/0{$i} ~/index_new/ > ~/results/actors_results/0{$i}.txt
            echo "INDEXING ($i)th directory completed "

    else
            nohup java BeginIndex ~/actors/{$i} ~/index_new/ > ~/results/actors_results/{$i}.txt
            echo "INDEXING ($i)th directory completed "
    fi
done
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this script? do I need to do #!/bin/bash first? Also, can i nohup this script the way it's written or do I have to remove the nohup in the if-else statements? I don't really know all the syntax of if-else and for loops for bash... sorry if this is such a simple question. I appreciate the help!

**Edit (posting an update from comments)**

I'm trying to index a directory called actors, with 1000 subdirectories with files inside them. the java program will run, but it can't handle all the files in these 1000 directories (about 1.8million). I want to write a script that will do it subdirectory at a time.

I'm ssh'ing into a server to do this, but it will take a while so I want it to not drop. I can't just run the java program on the whole directory, because it runs out of heap memory. It's not the most efficient java code, but I'm working on another solution to that problem while this script runs subdirectory-at-a-time.

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to do? Only then can we say what is wrong with it.

Comment: have you tried providing absolute paths instead of relative paths (using `~`) to the program? Also, can clarify on what is wrong with the script currently? Note - nohup is fine and it should work; you might want to append `&` at the end so that it will run in the background instead of blocking. Finally, please update the question with more info, instead of posting them in comments.

Comment: Ohhh sorry I just added those ~'s because they are all in different folders and I didn't want to clutter the screen :) I think I'll try  Kerrek's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [test](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html) command is definitely wrong.

Just remember `"["` in bash is a command, not a syntax. It expects the string `"]"` as the last argument. This is why spaces are **required** before and after them. (Semicolon is OK, because it is a part of the syntax)

Also, as Kerrek pointed out, the comparation operator is `-lt` not `lt`.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to edit the folder names because 00{$i} wasnt returning 00i like I wanted. but I figured it out myself. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

The test functions need a hyphen in front of the option:

```
if [ $i -lt 10 ] ; then
    # ....
fi
```

Note that `[` is just an ordinary command, usually in `/usr/bin/[`, and it has to be treated as such.

Comment: thank you, but im getting :

[aengle@ ~]$ ./script.sh 
./script.sh: line 5: [0: command not found
./script.sh: line 9: [0: command not found

Comment: @aengle1429: Sorry, forgot the space!